# What is the purpose of TaskExecutor in spring?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, task

What is the purpose of TaskExecutor in spring. What problem does it solve ? How is it different from Executors in java concurrent package ?

Comment: The purpose is to execute arbitrary Tasks :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/scheduling.html

23.4. The Spring TaskExecutor abstraction

...

**Spring's TaskExecutor interface is identical to the java.util.concurrent.Executor interface. In fact, its primary reason for existence is to abstract away the need for Java 5 when using thread pools.** The interface has a single method execute(Runnable task) that accepts a task for execution based on the semantics and configuration of the thread pool.

...

Comment: So if we are using Java 5, there is no need to bother about the TaskExecutor abstraction ?

Comment: If you want to use java.util.concurrent.Executor, you can use it safely, because they are basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interface whose implementations wrap around Java 5+ `ExecutorService` and provide implementations for previous versions of Java that are missing the package `java.util.concurrent`