# How to use single "application wide" thread pool in Spring MVC app running on Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, concurrency, threadpool

For simpler control over application performance I want to use one application wide thread pool. Our app uses Tomcat as web server, Spring and, on the lower level, makes a lot of calls to external APIs. I need some of this external calls run asynchronously, and want to use for this purpose same thread pool as Tomcat uses for client request service.

Firstly, I thought that I can somehow obtain Tomcat thread pool and then use it, but after some googling I haven't found a way to do it.

My second thought was to set custom thread pool for Tomcat and also use it in other places, where I need async calls. But I haven't found how to implement it also.

Any help and advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check examples here, very useful for you I think. http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/

Comment: @bureaquete thanks, but can't see how it can help me. I found answer about spring TaskExecutor and it says that it purpouse is to give pre-java5 user ability to use thread pool. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209864/what-is-the-purpose-of-taskexecutor-in-spring. I use Java 8 and has all the pools I need, but what I'm really looking for is a way how to use ONE thread pool for my entire application including Tomacat.

Answer (score 1):

Choose [task executor abstractions from Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Comment: @maggu thanks for your answer, but as I have read Spring TaskExecutor is the same as java5 Executor service. I need something else I think...

Comment: From [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) : Spring’s TaskExecutor interface is identical to the java.util.concurrent.Executor interface. In fact, its primary reason for existence was to abstract away the need for Java 5 when using thread pools